# python-cloudant document update error handling

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling, couchdb, python-cloudant

i've just started using the python-cloudant library for my couchdb related database queries. I implemented a module for database connection. However i'm not sure how to use the [python-cloudant errors documentation](http://python-cloudant.readthedocs.io/en/latest/error.html) to help me tell when an operation fails. Forexample i'm updating a document and i really don't know if the operation was successful or not. Below is my database connection module.

**couchmodule.py**

```
class CouchdbAk:
    def __init__(self):
        self.client = self.connect()
        self.db = self.opendb()
        self.filemodule = FileModule()

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        self.client.disconnect()

    def connect(self):
        return CouchDB(constants.USERNAME, constants.PASSWORD, account=constants.ACCOUNT_NAME, url=constants.DBHOST,
                       connect=True, auto_renew=True)

    def disconnect(self):
        self.client.disconnect()

    def opendb(self):
        return self.client[constants.DBNAME]

    def updatedoc(self, id, newvalues):

        doc = self.db[id]
        for key in newvalues:
            doc[key] = newvalues[key]
        doc.save()
```

Comment: Your operations will raise one of the Cloudant exception if an error occurs. You have to try catch them

Comment: So thats actually bothering me, it doesn't throw any error even when the doc.saves() doesn't work. So i'm wondering how i can detect it